# Showing a bijective, continuous function between connected, locally euclidean spaces is a homeomorphism.

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology, manifolds, geometric-topology

This question comes from Conlon's Differentiable Manifolds (it's Exercise 1.1.13).

Let $X$ and $Y$ be connected, locally Euclidean spaces of the same dimension.  If $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is bijective and continuous, prove that $f$ is a homeomorphism.

---

I think I need to use the local homeomorphism $\Rightarrow$ global homeomorphism idea, but I'm having trouble constructing the local homeomorphism.  Obviously if I were to do so these local homeomorphisms would have to come from composing the homeos that we have into $\mathbb{R}^n$, but I keep having trouble because we don't know $f$ is a homeo yet.  Am I even on the right track?

Comment: I won't claim this is a full answer, but I think you may want to show that any bijective continuous function between to open sets in euclidean space is an open map, and then this should follow. EDIT: This may be using a flamethrower to get rid of leaves in the lawn, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59532/bijective-continuous-function-on-mathbb-rn-not-homeomorphism

Comment: @JohnStalfos A bijective continuous function between two open sets in a Euclidean space should be a local homeomorphism because a bijective continuous function from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is a homemorphism. Now a bijective local homeomorphism is a homeomorphism. Doesn't this settle what you state without Invariance of Domain?

Comment: @caffeinemachine This is not quite right. What prevents the map from taking an open ball to an open interval while somehow still being bijective and continuous?

Comment: @FanZheng You are right. My reasoning is not proper. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

OK, try this.

It is enough to show that $f^{-1}$ is continuous.  So suppose $f(x) = y$ and $x \in U_x$ where $U_x$ is open.  We want an open $U_y$ such that $y \in U_y \subseteq f(U_x)$.

Since $Y$ is locally Euclidean, we can get an open $B_y \simeq \mathbb{R}^n$ with $y \in B_y$.  $f$ is continuous, so $f^{-1}(B_y)$ is open.  $U_x \cap f^{-1}(B_y)$ is also open.  Since $X$ is locally Euclidean, we can get an open $B_x \simeq \mathbb{R}^n$ with $x \in B_x \subseteq U_x \cap f^{-1}(B_y)$.

Now consider the map $f': \mathbb{R}^n \simeq B_x \to f(B_x) \to B_y \simeq \mathbb{R}^n$.  Each step is injective and continuous, so $f'$ is also injective and continuous.  Now we can use Invariance of Domain (thank you @John Stalfos!) to conclude that $f'$ is open.  In particular, $f(B_x)$ is open in $B_y$, and since $B_y$ is open in $Y$, $f(B_x)$ is open in $Y$.  Now it's clear that we can choose $U_y$ above to be $f(B_x)$.  QED.

Comment: which part need connectness? please see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4769841/question-about-a-proof-of-bijective-continuous-function-between-connected-lo)

Comment: @zhoupengshan, good question. I think you are correct in your related question: connectedness is not needed. Conlon might use it to avoid cases like $\Bbb{R}^1 \coprod \Bbb{R}^2$ whose dimension is not uniquely defined.

Comment: thanks a lot.i have been thinking about this homework question for a week actually......