# Properties of a one to one continuous function from $[0, 1]$ onto itself

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $f$ be a one to one continuous function from $[0, 1]$ onto itself. Show that

(i) $f$ is a homeomorphism.

(ii) $f$ is strictly monotone on $[0, 1]$

(iii) Is it true that if $f$ is strictly monotone on $[0, 1]$ and onto $[0, 1]$, then $f$ is continuous?

For (iii) I am sure it will be true as monotone function has only jump discontinuity so if it is onto it has to be continuous as well. This is my intuition only, more rigorous argument is welcome, thank you.

Comment: ProofWiki: [Continuous Function on Closed Interval is Bijective iff Strictly Monotone](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Function_on_Closed_Interval_is_Bijective_iff_Strictly_Monotone). 
Related question: [A continuous bijection $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is an homeomorphism?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145639/a-continuous-bijection-f-mathbbr-to-mathbbr-is-an-homeomorphism)

Comment: yes bijecive map from compect space to hausdorff space must be homeo :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i) Because $[0,1]$ is compact and Hausdorff, $f$ is a homeomophism.

ii) Any one-one continuous function (on $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$) is strictly monotone.

iii) If $f$ is not continuous, at some point $a\in (0,1)$ we have:
$$\lim_{x\to a^-}f(x)\ne \lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)$$
$$\Rightarrow \sup_{x<a}f(x)< \inf_{a<x}f(x)$$
$$\Rightarrow \sup f([0,a))< \inf f((a,1])$$
So $f([0,1])\ne [0,1]$ .

Comment: I want this answer be deleted.