# Example of a continuous function with a discontinuous inverse

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, examples-counterexamples, inverse

What is an example of a function $f: \Bbb R^n \rightarrow \Bbb R^m$ such that $f$ is continuous and injective but that $f^{-1}$ is not continuous.

Our professor teased us with the notion but I haven't been able to think of such a function.

Comment: Related post: [Functions which are Continuous, but not Bicontinuous](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68800/functions-which-are-continuous-but-not-bicontinuous). Maybe also other posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/68800) might be of interest.

Comment: For the case $m=n$ see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59532/bijective-continuous-function-on-mathbb-rn-not-homeomorphism). For the case $m=n=1$ see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145639/a-continuous-bijection-f-mathbbr-to-mathbbr-is-an-homeomorphism). (Although both questions are about bijective rather than injective functions.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ to be a function which performs an eight-shaped figure in the way described [here](http://sketchtoy.com/66813624) (as $x \rightarrow -\infty$, it tends to the origin, and also as $x \rightarrow \infty$).

For topological reasons, the inverse cannot be continuous.

Note that if $n=m$, then the inverse must be continuous, and this is a result of the [Invariance of Domain Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain). (If $n=m=1$, a direct proof through methods of real analysis can be easily achieved)

Answer (score 12):

The standard example (though not from $\mathbb R^n$ but rather a subset)

$f:[0,2\pi) \to S^1$, $f(x) = (\cos(x),\sin(x))$

$f^{-1}$ is not continuous at $(1,0)$.

Comment: This is not a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo You're right, I misinterpreted the question.

Comment: @Winther No, because that way a point will be missing from the circle, and the inverse will be continuous (since a circle with a point missing is homeomorphic to the line).

Comment: @AloizioMacedo Thanks for clearing that up.