# Is a continuous bijection $f:\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ a homeomorphism?

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity, inverse-function

Let $X$ be an open subset of $\mathbb K$, $f: X \to \mathbb K$, and $Y:=f(X)$.

> [Theorem:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145639/a-continuous-bijection-f-mathbbr-to-mathbbr-is-an-homeomorphism) If $\mathbb K = \mathbb R$, and $f$ is injective and continous, then $f^{-1}:Y \to X$ is continuous.

The proof relies on the order of $\mathbb R$. Does above theorem hold if we replace $\mathbb R$ by $\mathbb C$?

Comment: What about $f(z) = e^{z}$? Or $z^2$?

Comment: @preferred_anon The exponential is not injective.

Comment: @preferred_anon You forgot the word *bijection*.

Comment: It's true, see [invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain). You may want to study it from a textbook.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Thank you so much for your help! Do you have any suggestion of textbook containing this theorem?

Comment: @Analyst You can find it as theorem 2B.3 in Allen Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*, which is notoriously free to download from the author's website.