# Can this powerful version of inverse function theorem be extended to $\mathbb C^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, inverse-function-theorem

I'm reading inverse function theorem (IVT) at page 306 of Amann's *Analysis I*, i.e.,

> **Amann's IVT:** Let $X$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{K} \in \{\mathbb{C}, \mathbb{R}\}, f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$, and $Y:=f(X)$. Let $f$ be injective and consider the inverse $f^{-1}: Y \rightarrow X$ of $f$. Suppose that $f$ is differentiable at $a \in X$, and $f^{-1}$ is continuous at $b:=f(a) \in Y$. Then $f^{-1}$ is differentiable at $b$ if and only if $f^{\prime}(a) \neq 0$. In this case, $\left(f^{-1}\right)^{\prime}(b)=1 / f^{\prime}(a)$.

This version does **not** require $f'$ to be continuous, which distinguishes itself from the [standard version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem#Statements). Moreover, a continuous bijection $f:\mathbb C \to Y \subset\mathbb C$ is a homeomorphism by [invariance of domain theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4540162/is-a-continuous-bijection-f-mathbb-c-to-mathbb-c-a-homeomorphism#comment9545466_4540162). So Amann's IVT is indeed powerful.

I would like to ask if Amann's version can be extended to multivariate setting, i.e.,

> Let $X$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{K}^n$ where $\mathbb{K} \in \{\mathbb{C}, \mathbb{R}\}, f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{K}^n$, and $Y:=f(X)$. Let $f$ be injective and consider the inverse $f^{-1}: Y \rightarrow X$ of $f$. Suppose that $f$ is differentiable at $a \in X$, and $f^{-1}$ is continuous at $b:=f(a) \in Y$. Then $f^{-1}$ is differentiable at $b$ if and only if $f^{\prime}(a)$ is invertible. In this case, $\left(f^{-1}\right)^{\prime}(b)=[f^{\prime}(a)]^{-1}$.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Calling this the inverse function theorem is very strange. It is much more elementary than inverse function theorem.

Comment: Yes, the hypotheses are weaker, but the conclusions are markedly weaker. This is just the computation of a derivative.