# M compact  $p\in M$ , there exist $f:M-p\to M-p$ continuous bijection but not homeomorphism?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness, examples-counterexamples

Let M be a compact metric space. We know that if $ g:M\to M$ is a continuous bijection then it's a homeomorphism. But I want to know, if I have a continuous bijection $
f:M - \left\{ p \right\} \to M - \left\{ p \right\}
$, then it's true that can always be extended to a continuous bijection $M\to M$ or not?

clearly I assume that  $
M - \left\{ p \right\}
$ it's under the restricted metric of M.

EDITED: Even knowing that M it's the one point compactification and that the open sets of M are all the open sets of M-p , and the complement of compacts of M-p , even with that I can't prove the result. Maybe it's not true. I'm not sure, if you want to use that you are welcome, and maybe it's false and I need a counterexample :/
I'll also change the name of the post

Comment: Hmm...is it true that $M$ will be $M-p$'s one point compactification?

Comment: @uncookedfalcon: yes, and this holds for any compact $M$ (not necessarily metrizable).

Comment: How can I prove this?

Comment: Yes the unique option is to send p to p, but how can I prove that this extension is continuous?

Comment: Check out munkres thm 29.1 (http://search.4shared.com/postDownload/QLRvEhXV/book_topology__2ed_-_james_mun.html) (the answer is yes, it always extends)

Comment: I can't use compactification by a point, Well... the original question was this " Let  $ f:
S^n  - \left\{ p \right\} \to S^n  - \left\{ p \right\}
$ be a continuous bijection, can be extended to a bijection of $ S^n$?  in other words. Let $
\left( {x_n } \right) \in S^n  - \left\{ p \right\} \subset S^n 
$ it's true that $
f\left( {x_n } \right) \to p
$? (this is equivalent to prove that there exist a continuous extension, since the extension must fix p )

Comment: But $S^n$ is the one point compactification of $S^n - \{p\}$...

Comment: But not using compactification by one point, we did not see that in my course, we did not see the definition of a topology, only metric spaces )= so I can use it , sorry, I know how to do it with that, but I want to know if I can do it only with elementary tools (of metric spaces)

Comment: @uncookedfalcon: I can't see how Munkres 29.1 helps, could you elaborate?

Comment: No help, because it's assuming that the map between $M-p \to M-p$ it's not only bijective continuous , it's also a homeomorphism.

Comment: Since $S^n-\{p\}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$, we know that every continuous bijection is a homeomorphism, see this question: [bijective continuous function on $\mathbb R^n$ not homeomorphism?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59532/bijective-continuous-function-on-mathbb-rn-not-homeomorphism)
P. L. Clark claims in [his answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/59537/) to that question that: *This argument should work with $\mathbb R^n$ replaced by any metric space in which a subset is compact iff it is closed and bounded.*

Comment: Addendum to my earlier comment: Only now I've noticed comments bellow Pete L. Clark's answer, which cast some doubt on the claim I copied... :-(

Comment: @Matias yeah sorry man, I implicitly was thinking of $M-p \rightarrow M-p$ as a homeomorphism

Comment: @Matias: you accepted my answer, but it is incorrect. See my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**WARNING:** I just noticed there are two big problems with my answer. The closed upper half plane is *not* homeomorphic to the space $X$ obtained by removing an open interval from the boundary of a closed 2-disk. It is true that $X$ has a continuous self bijection which is not a homeomorphism given by folding the boundary in on itself, but $X$ is *not locally compact* so my example does not solve your problem. However, my link is still relevant because Jim Belk's answer on the same page exhibits a continuous self-bijection of a locally compact space.

---

As has been pointed out, the spaces obtained by subtracting a point from a compact Hausdorff space are precisely the locally compact Hausdorff spaces. So your question can be rephrased as follows.

> Does there exist a continuous self-bijection of a (necessarily noncompact) locally compact Hausdorff space which is not a homeomorphism?

<strike>This is possible even for as nice a space as the upper half plane</strike>  $\mathbb{H}^2 = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y \geq 0\}$ (a manifold with boundary!).

We can also identify $\mathbb{H}^2$ with a closed 2-disk minus a point on the boundary. <strike>Or, more usefully, a closed 2-disk with an open interval subtracted from the boundary</strike>. Now there is a clear self-bijection given by tucking the boundary in on itself and this is not a homeomorphism. For a picture, see my answer here.

[Are continuous self-bijections of connected spaces homeomorphisms?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20913/are-continuous-self-bijections-of-connected-spaces-homeomorphisms/20932#20932)

Answer (score 9):

I will denote by $C(\omega)=\{0,1,2,\dots\}\cup\{\omega\}$ the [one-point compactification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_compactification) of the discrete space on the countable set $\{0,1,2,\dots\}$.
I.e. all points different from $\omega$ are isolated and neighborhoods of $\omega$ are precisely complements of finite subsets of $\{0,1,2,\dots\}$.
(This space is homeomorphic to the space $\{0\}\cup\{\frac1{n+1}; n=0,1,2,\dots\}$ with the topology inherited from real line. So this is simply a convergent sequence.)

Now I take $M=\{0,1\}\times C(\omega)$, where $\{0,1\}$ has the discrete topology. (I.e., $M$ is the topological sum of two copies of $C(\omega)$.) And I choose $p=(0,\omega)$.

It is easy to see that $M$ is a compact metric space.
(E.g. it is homeomorphic to $\{0,1\}\times(\{0\}\cup\{\frac1{n+1}; n=0,1,2,\dots\})$ with the topology induced by the usual Euclidean metric on $\mathbb R^2$.)
Note that every subset of $\{0\}\times C(\omega)$ is open in $M\setminus\{p\}$.

Let us define a map $f \colon M\setminus\{p\} \to M\setminus\{p\}$ by putting
$$f(0,2n)=(1,2n)\\
f(0,2n+1)=(0,n)\\
f(1,n)=(1,2n+1)\\
f(1,\omega)=(1,\omega).$$

This map is bijective and continuous, but the extension $\overline f\colon M\to M$ with $\overline f(0,\omega)=(0,\omega)$ is not continuous, since the sequence $x_n=(0,2n)$ converges to $(0,\omega)$ in $M$ but $\overline f(x_n)=(1,2n)$ converges to $(1,\omega)\ne \overline f(0,\omega)$.

---

Here's my attempt to sketch the above map (the two big arrows indicate the direction in which the sequences $C(\omega)\times\{0\}$ and $C(\omega)\times\{1\}$ converge):

[image: Two copies of C(omega)]

---

It is perhaps worth mentioning that $f^{-1}$ is not continuous. The sequence $(1,2n)$ converges to $(1,\omega)$ but $f^{-1}(1,2n)=(0,2n)$ does not converge.

So this does not contradict Theorem 29.1 from Munkres, which was mentioned in comments.

> **Theorem 29.1.** Let $X$ be a space. Then $X$ is locally compact Hausdorff if and only
>   if there exists a space $Y$ satisfying the following conditions:
>
> - $X$ is a subspace of $Y$.
> - The set $Y-X$ consists of a single point.
> - $Y$ is a compact Hausdorff space.
>
> If $Y$ and $Y'$ are two spaces satisfying these conditions, then there is a homeomorphism
>   of $Y$ with $Y'$ that equals the identity map on $x$.

---

The OP indicated that he was originally thinking about the case that $M=S^n$. Since $S^n$ is the one-point compactification of $\mathbb R^n$, from Theorem 29.1 and from the fact that every continuous bijection $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ is a homeomorphism (which was shown in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59532/bijective-continuous-function-on-mathbb-rn-not-homeomorphism)) we get that in the case $M=S^n$ the result from the question is true.

Comment: Very nice.  I spent quite a while trying to come up with an example but didn't succeed.

Comment: @Martin Sleziak Thanks Martin! I wanted to know if this was true, because if the result was true, I could prove that every continuous bijection from $ R^n \to R^n$ is a homeomorphism (working in $S^n$ the one point compactification of $R^n$).  Do you think that would help, to prove that result working in $S^n-p$ instead of $R^n$ ? And how can I give you the reward of $100$ points? I don't know

Comment: @Matias If I were you, I would wait a little before awarding a bounty - perhaps you'll get more answer and it is possible that someone will spot a mistake in my answer. Anyway, I think that anything you need to know about bounties, you can find at [faq](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty) and [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bounty). I've tried to add something about $S^n$, I am not sure whether this is what you wanted to see.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks again for the answer! But I'm not sure if the proofs there are good.

Comment: @Matias Just let me know what seems to be a problem - I'll try to work out the details. (Another possibility - we will find out that there is a mistake.)

Answer (score 1):

I'll add another example which I found at [Ask A Topologist](http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_a_topologist_2008;task=show_msg;msg=0976.0001.0001.0002) forum. This example is, to some extent, similar to the example above, but it might be easier to visualize.

---

I'll first put here a LaTeX-ed version of the post I linked:

This is an example of a [locally compact space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_space) $S$ and a continuous bijective function $f\colon S\to S$, which is not a homeomorphism.

Let $S = \bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb Z} S_n \cup \{0\}$, where $S_n$ is the circle centered at the origin with radius $2^n$.
$S$ is a locally compact space as a closed subset of $\mathbb C$.
Define, for $m$ and $n$ in $\mathbb Z$, $f_{m, n} \colon S_m \to S_n$ homeomorphism (for example the multiplication by $2^{n-m}$).
Then define a bijection $g \colon \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ such that $g (n) \to - \infty$ when $n \to -\infty$ and $g (n)$ is not bounded above nor bounded below when $n \to +\infty$.
For example, $g$ defined by $g (n) = n/2$ if $n$ is positive and even, $g (n) = -n$ if $n$ is positive and odd, and $g (n) = -2n$ if $n$ is negative should work.

Now, consider
$f \colon S \to S$
$$ x \mapsto f_{n, g (n)} (x),\\
 0 \mapsto 0$$

$f$ is an bijection from $S_n$ to $S_{g (n)}$ for every $n$ and since $g$ is permutation of $\mathbb Z$, $f$ is a bijection from $S - \{0\}$ to $S - \{0\}$.
$f$ sends $0$ to $0$, therefore $f$ is a bijection from $S$ to $S$.
$f$ is continuous on each $S_n$, and is continuous at $0$ since $g (n) \to -\infty$ when $n \to -\infty$.
But $f^{-1}$ is not continuous at zero, because $g^{-1} (n) \not\to -\infty$ when $n \to -\infty$.

---

Now let us consider $\mathbb C\cup\{\infty\}$ as the [one-point-compactification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_compactification) of plane.

Then we have subspace $M=S\cup\{\infty\}$.

The map $f \colon S\to S$ described above is continuous and bijective, but the extension $\overline f \colon M \to M$ such that $\overline f(\infty)=\infty$ is not continuous.
To see this, just choose a sequence $(x_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ such that $x_n \in S_n$ and observe that $x_n\to\infty$ but $\overline f(x_n)=f(x_n)$ does not converge to $\infty$.

---

Interestingly, when I was Googling and trying to find similar examples online, I found the following sentence [in some book](http://books.google.com/books?id=QG9f1Dn_RlwC&pg=PA90):

> This finishes the proof of the theorem, since every continuous bijection between locally compact Hausdorff spaces is a homeomorphism (see Theorem 10 on page 139 of [Eng68]).

It seems that [Eng68] refers to the book R. Engelking (1968). *Outline of General Topology.* translated from Polish. North-Holland, Amsterdam.

I only have the Polish original of this book; which of course has a different page numbering; but I did not find in the chapter on locally compact spaces anything similar to the above claim. So I guess it is a mistake or (more probably) a misquote.

Comment: The statement you quote in the last part is blatantly wrong. The identity from the discrete reals to the reals with the usual topology is an obvious counterexample. Also, there's [a result of Parhomenko](http://mi.mathnet.ru/eng/izv/v5/i3/p225) saying that every locally compact space admits a 1-1 continuous function onto a compact Hausdorff space (see also exercise 3.3.D in Engelking).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. (I did not know about this result.) Of course, I agree that the claim as quoted is not correct. (Unfortunately, I am not able to follow the proof where it is used, so I am not sure to which extent is this mistake important for the result from that book). Anyway - just out of curiosity - if I am able to get somewhere Engelking's Outline of GT, I'll have a look what exactly is Theorem 10 on p.139.