# Continuity of the inverse $f^{-1}$ at $f(x)$ when $f$ is bijective and continuous at $x$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, examples-counterexamples, inverse

> Prove or disprove: Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be bijective and $f$ is continuous at $x$. Then $f^{-1}$ is continuous at $f(x)$.

Any hints are welcome. If this is false, I would like to have a counterexample.

I tried the $\epsilon,\delta$ argument and I know this statement may not be true. But this problem only tells the continuity at a single point, and the function may not be monotone, for example:

$$f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R},\quad f(x)=\begin{cases}x,&x\in\mathbb{Q}\\
-x,&x\notin\mathbb{Q}\end{cases}$$

This function is bijective and is only continuous at $0$, and it is not monotone.

Comment: Start with the definition of "continuous at x."  Attempt to massage this into the definition of "$f^{-1}$ continuous at $f(x)$."  You'll either succeed or get stuck; in the latter case, figure out why you got stuck and produce a counterexample exploiting that.

Comment: Consider an $\varepsilon$, $\delta$ argument.

Comment: Whoops! Misread that. My apologies.

Comment: Your example function isn't continuous anywhere...

Comment: Also note that a function must have it's domain and co-domain defined to really consider bijectivity. The $f(x)$ that you placed there seems to simply be a formula

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the following could be a counterexample.

Let us define $f \colon [0,3] \to [0,3]$ as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
f\left(\frac 1n\right)&=\frac1{2n}; \text{ for }n=1,2,3,\dots;\\
f\left(3-\frac1{2n-1}\right)&=\frac1{2n-1}; \text{ for }n=1,2,3,\dots;\\
f\left(3-\frac1{2n}\right)&=3-\frac1{n}; \text{ for }n=1,2,3,\dots;\\
f(x)&=x; \text{ if $x$ does not have the form $\frac1n$ or $3-\frac1n$}
\end{align}
$$

In other words, we are working only with points of the form $1/n$ and $3-1/n$ and we do not move other points. The points of the form $1/n$ are mapped to $1/(2n)$. So far we do not have anything mapped onto points of the form $1/(2n+1)$, so we use half of the points of the form $2-\frac1n$ to get something mapped onto them.

The function $f$ is bijective, it is continuous at $0$, but $f^{-1}$ is not continuous at $0$. (To see this just take $x_n=\frac1{2n+1}$ and notice that $x_n\to0$ and $f^{-1}(x_n)\to3$.)

The basic idea is very similar to general "[Hilbert's hotel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_hotel)" idea, like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/160742/) and in many other constructions of bijections. I hope that, at least to some extent, I managed to capture the construction in the following picture, which might help you ti visualize this example.

[image]

EDIT: I've added one more version of the picture. The dotted lines might make easier to see which of the "full" and "empty" circles have the same x-coordinates/the same y-coordinates.

[image]

Comment: I've spent about 30-40 minutes going over this post and must say this is fascinating. I've never seen anything like this in particular, but it really is quite *cool*. My thought on a proof was more along the lines of showing how the bijectvity doesn't imply a continuous distribution of the values of $f$ (which seems to be exactly what you have done here, however I've never seen a function actually created to do this!). All in all very cool! Thank you!

Comment: @DanZimm I hope I did not make a mistake there and the counterexample is correct. The basic idea is similar to an example I've constructed in [an answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154090/m-compact-p-in-m-there-exist-fm-p-to-m-p-continuous-bijection-but-not-ho/155106#155106) to another question. Probably there are many different approaches how to find a function answering this question. So there might by simpler (or more interesting) examples.

Comment: as far as I can tell there are no mistakes. It's quite the witty construction of a function :D

Comment: On the right side of the picture, the dots seem upside down? (if I didn't get it wrong)

Comment: @delt3 I hope it is correct now after my edit.

Comment: Yes, I think it's corrected. Thanks!

Comment: Can you extend this to make $f$ differentiable at $0$?

Comment: Have to say this is neat! My above question can be solved really easily! Congratulations.

Answer (score 2):

So first I would consider what a bijective function is:

> A function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is bijective if it's both injective and surjective.

Next let's look at what surjective and injective mean:

> A function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is injective given that $x \neq y \implies f(x) \neq f(y)$

and surjective:

> A function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is surjective if $\forall \; y \in \mathbb{R} \; \exists \; x \in \mathbb{R} \; s.t. \; f(x) = y$ or in set notation $f(\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{R}$

Now given some $x \in \mathbb{R}$ let's look at the definition of continuity at a point.

> A function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $x$ if $\forall \; \epsilon > 0 \; \exists \; \delta > 0 \; s.t. \; \lvert x - y \rvert < \delta \implies \lvert f(x) - f(y) \rvert < \epsilon$ or more concisely, and assuming there aren't any isolated points: $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = f(x_0)$

Ok now we know this function is surjective (since it's bijective) and so we know there aren't any isolated points that $f$ takes (let me know if you don't understand any of this, I just realized I might be talking about too advanced of things for this question) so we can use the second definition of continuity of $f$. So we know

$$
\lim_{y \to x} f(y) = f(x)
$$

Now if we look at the inverse function, we know it is as well bijective (a bijective function has a bijective inverse - not sure if you're allowed to assume this, if you're not a simple proof by contradiction could work). Now our goal is to show that

$$
\lim_{y \to f(x)} f^{-1}(y) = f^{-1} (f(x)) = x
$$

Does this help at all? Do you need any more ideas?

Comment: I understand the $\epsilon,\delta$ stuff perfectly and I clearly understand what you are saying. The trouble is, this problem does not say any thing about the continuity of $f$ on the domain, only the continuity at a single point. I think this is the reason I am stuck.

Comment: @Katoyu why do you need continuity of the entire domain?

Comment: 1) May I ask whoever downvoted, why?

Comment: 2) @Katoyu you only need to prove that the inverse is continuous at $f(x)$ not for the entire domain, so why do you need continuity of the entire domain?

Comment: I am not saying the continuity of the entire domain is needed. If the function is continuous on the entire domain, then it is much easier. Also, I believe that the example function I provided is continuous at $x=0$. It is not difficult to check from definition.

Comment: @Katoyu right, that was my bad, didn't realize it took values of $x$ and $-x$ respectively. Notice that the inverse of this function would be the function itself, and so the inverse function is continuous at $x=0$ as well - look to Martin's answer for a great example!

Comment: @DanZimm This might have been downvoted because it provides no concrete solution, but just goes over some definitions. I didn't downvoted, I am just guessing.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff ok, good point (I was trying to give hints as opposed to a solution, but the downvote is understandable)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a much simpler answer...

Consider $(\mathbb{R},d)$ and $(\mathbb{R},d_{\text{disc}})$ where $d$ is the standard metric and $d_{\text{disc}}$ is the discrete metric. Then, consider the identity mappings $$\iota: (\mathbb{R},d) \to (\mathbb{R},d_{\text{disc}})$$ and
$$\iota^{-1}: (\mathbb{R},d_{\text{disc}}) \to  (\mathbb{R},d).$$ Notice that one of these is continuous (you should quickly see which one) and is clearly bijective, but the inverse is not.