# Example of a continuous bijection on $\mathbb R^n$ whose inverse is not continuous

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

For $n \ge 2$  give example of a bijective continuous map $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ whose inverse is not continuous ; example of such a function is also an example of  [Does there exist a bijection of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with itself such that the forward map is connected but the inverse is not?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/952466/does-there-exist-a-bijection-of-mathbbrn-with-itself-such-that-the-forward)

Comment: There is no such function due to "invariance of domain". http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain

Comment: @PhoemueX: what is "invariance of domain" ??

Comment: I edited my comment and provided a link. It is a theorem telling you that an injective continuous map $f : U \to \Bbb{R}^n$ with $U \subset \Bbb{R}^n$ open is always an open map, so that the inverse is also continuous.