# $X$ be a complete metric space and $f:X \to X$ be a bijective and connected preserving map ; then is $f^{-1}$ also connected preserving?

Tags: metric-spaces, connectedness

Let $X$ be a complete metric space and $f:X \to X$ be bijective and a connected preserving map i.e. $f$ carries every connected set of $X$ to a connected set of $X$ ; then is it necessarily true that $f^{-1}$  also carries connected sets to connected sets ?

Comment: So are you supposing that $f$ is bijective?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/952466/does-there-exist-a-bijection-of-mathbbrn-with-itself-such-that-the-forward

Answer (score 9):

Let 
$$X=\bigl(\{-2\}\cup [-1,0]\cup [1,\infty)\bigr)\times \Bbb N_0$$
with the induced metric as a subspace of $\Bbb R^2$.
This space is complete. 
The connected subspaces are precisely those of the form $I\times\{n\}$ where $n\in\Bbb N_0$ and either $I=\{-2\}$ or $I$ is an interval $\subseteq [-1,0]$ or $I$ is an interval $\subseteq [0,\infty)$.

Consider the map $f\colon X\to X$ given by 
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}(-\frac1x,y)&\text{if $x>0$ and $y=0$}\\
(0,0)&\text{if $x=-2$ and $y=0$}\\
(x,y+1)&\text{if $-1\le x\le 0$}\\
(x,y-1)&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases} $$
This is a continuous bijection and preserves connectedness.
But its inverse maps the connected set $[-1,0]\times \{0\}$ to the not connected set $\bigl(\{-2\}\cup [1,\infty)\bigr)\times\{0\}$.

The thing works a bit like a zipper:

[image]

Comment: If I'm not mistaken , the inverse map is $f^{-1}(z)=\sqrt z$ ,  which is continuous , and hence connected preserving

Comment: your map is not injective ; $f(i)=f(-i)$

Comment: @SaunDev The bijectivity condition was added to the problem statement a day after my answer was posted ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Should that $\frac{1}{x}$ be $-\frac{1}{x}$?

Comment: @MarcPaul Yes, I'll fix

Comment: +1.I don't think you can find a better answer then this.