# Is a path-connected bijection $f\colon \Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}^n$ continuous?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, real-numbers, connectedness, path-connected

While thinking about [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/952466/60589) question I was asking myself if a path-connected bijection $f\colon \Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}^n$ has to be continuous for $n>1$?

If we drop the requirement that $f$ is bijective, then it is not true as in the connected case.

I was wondering if this question is maybe easier? I have no intuition if it is true or not. On one hand I think there are too many connected sets, there will be some ugly counterexample, on the other hand the reals are "nice".

By a path-connected function I mean a function between topological spaces whose image of a path-connected set is path-connected.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's how you can get a counterexample for $n>2$ assuming the continuum hypothesis.  Note that if $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is path-connected and $x,y\in A$, there is a path-connected closed subset $B\subseteq A$ containing $x$ and $y$ (namely, the image of a path between them).  So for $f$ to be path-connected, it suffices for $f(A)$ to be path-connected whenever $A$ is a *closed* path-connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

This is very useful, because there are only $\mathfrak{c}$ different closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$.  First, partition $\mathbb{R}^n$ into $\mathfrak{c}$ sets $(S_\alpha)_{\alpha<\mathfrak{c}}$, each of which intersects every closed path-connected subset with more than one point at $\mathfrak{c}$ points (you can do this by an induction of length $\mathfrak{c}$, where at the $\alpha$th stage you add a point of the $\gamma$th closed path-connected set to $S_\beta$ for all $\beta,\gamma<\alpha$).  Also, enumerate all quadruples $(A,x,y,u)$ where $A$ is a path-connected closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $x,y\in A$, and $u\in\mathbb{R}^n$ with order-type $\mathfrak{c}$.

Now define $f$ by an induction of length $\mathfrak{c}$.  At the $\alpha$th stage of the induction, we want to define $f$ on $\{x,y\}\cup (A\cap S_\alpha)$ such that $f(A\cap S_\alpha)$ contains a smooth path from $f(x)$ to $f(y)$, where $(A,x,y,u)$ is the $\alpha$th quadruple in our enumeration.  To do this, we need the following lemma (here is where we use CH and the fact that $n>2$):

> **Lemma**: Let $n>2$, let $a,b\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and let $g_1,g_2,\ldots:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be a countable collection of smooth paths and $c_1,c_2,\ldots\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be a countable collection of points distinct from $a$ and $b$.  Then there is a smooth path from $a$ to $b$ that does not intersect any of the $g_i$ except possibly at $a$ or $b$ and does not pass through any of the $c_i$.

To apply this lemma, let $a=f(x)$ and $b=f(y)$ (we may have already defined these values of $f$; if not, define them arbitrarily to be some points not in the image of $f$), let the $g_i$ be the smooth paths which we have already defined to be in the image of $f$ (there is one such path from each previous stage, so by CH, there are only countably many such paths), and let the $c_i$ be the other various points we have already defined to be in the image of $f$ (there are finitely many such points from each previous stage, so countably many in total by CH).  This gives us a smooth path from $a$ to $b$ which we can make the image of $f(A\cap S_\alpha)$ (except for the countably many points of $A\cap S_\alpha$ where we may have already defined $f$).  In addition, let us define $f$ at a couple more points to make sure $u$ is in both the domain and image of $f$.

At the end of this induction, we will have a path-connected bijection $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$.  It is easy to see that we can arrange for $f$ to be discontinuous (at the $\alpha$th stage, we are free to choose any bijection at all between $A\cap S_\alpha$ and our path).

It remains to prove the Lemma.  To do so, note that the space $P$ of all smooth paths from $a$ to $b$ is a complete metric space in the natural $C^\infty$ topology.  For each $i$, let $U_i$ be the set of smooth paths that do not pass through $c_i$.  For each $i$, let $V_i$ be the set of smooth paths that do not intersect $g_i$ unless $a$ and/or $b$ is in the image of $g_i$, in which case they intersect only at $a$ and/or $b$ and have different derivatives there.  Then by standard transversality theory (using the fact that $n>2$), each $U_i$ and $V_i$ is an open dense subset of $P$.  By the Baire category theorem, there is an element of $P$ that is every $C_i$ and $D_i$, and this is our desired path.

As a final note, I expect that CH is not actually necessary here.  However, I don't quite see how to prove a version of the Lemma that works for a collection of $<\mathfrak{c}$ paths, rather than just for a countable collection of paths.  [This question on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/216093/what-is-the-fewest-number-of-points-you-must-delete-from-mathbbr3-to-make) seems related to this issue.

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit lost at the moment. What does intersects at … points at $\mathfrak{c}$ points mean? For any closed path-connected $A$ there is a $\alpha$ such that $\vert A\cap S_{\alpha} \vert=\mathfrak{c}$? Could you explain in more detail why this exists? I also do not see what the $u$ is used for and how the quadruples are related to the indices $\alpha$.

Comment: I mean that for all $\alpha$ and all $A$, $|A\cap S_\alpha|=\mathfrak{c}$.  To do this, enumerate the $A$s as $(A_\alpha)_{\alpha<\mathfrak{c}}$, and run an induction of length $\mathfrak{c}$, where at the $\alpha$th stage, for each pair of ordinals $\beta,\gamma<\alpha$, you choose a point of $A_\beta$ and declare it to be an element of $S_\gamma$.  You can do this because at each stage, you have only picked $<\mathfrak{c}$ points from each $A_\beta$, and $|A_\beta|=\mathfrak{c}$.  At the end, you get that $|S_\gamma\cap A_\beta|=|\mathfrak{c}\setminus\max(\gamma,\beta)|=|\mathfrak{c}|$.

Comment: The point of $u$ is just to ensure that $f$ will end up being a bijection.  If we didn't include it, we might end up having some points that we never defined to be in the domain of $f$, or never made be in the image of $f$.  At the beginning of the construction, we choose an enumeration $(A_\alpha,x_\alpha,y_\alpha,u_\alpha)_{\alpha<\mathfrak{c}}$ of all such quadruples, and in the $\alpha$th stage of the induction we are using the quadruple $(A,x,y,u)=(A_\alpha, x_\alpha,y_\alpha,u_\alpha)$.

Comment: Sorry, needed some time to get comfortable with the solution. But I like the answer.  So you want that $u_{\alpha}$ is in the image of $f$ at the $\alpha$th stage, right? I am not sure why we do not need CH for the induction. Don't we need the fact that $\alpha < \mathfrak{c}$ is countable?

Comment: On the first question, that's right.  On the second question, I never said we don't need CH, and am assuming it...

Comment: I'll never understand why answers like these don't get more up votes. Excellent answer, very impressive.

Comment: @M10687 I think I can help. The easier it is to understand an answer, the more likely it is to get up votes. In many cases, when you look at the top answers of users, they are about fairly trivial stuff (even though the user might have given much better, more insteresting answers).