# Must injective path-connected maps/“path-Darboux” functions be continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, set-theory, path-connected

(Inspired by https://mathoverflow.net/questions/235893/does-there-exist-a-bijection-of-mathbbrn-to-itself-such-that-the-forward-m?rq=1)

Let us define a **Darboux function** or **connected map** to be a map between topological spaces that preserves connected sets (i.e. the image of any connected set is connected); and a **path-Darboux function** or **path-connected map** to be a map that preserves path-connected sets.

> **Conjecture:** every injective path-connected map $f:[0,1]\hookrightarrow \mathbb R^2$ has to be continuous.

I make several pathetic attempts at this Conjecture below and draw some pictures, but honestly I do not expect nor wish anyone to do anything more than barely skim through them.

***Preliminary Remarks:***

1. The converse is of course true: all continuous functions are path-connected maps.
2. Injectivity is important because of the example of "everywhere locally surjective" functions (functions whose images of any nonempty open set is the entire codomain), like the Conway Base-13 function, or [another example using the Riemann rearrangement theorem on the alternating harmonic series](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2933144/405572).
3. The **Conjecture** is true for $f: [0,1] \hookrightarrow \mathbb R$, because we know [all discontinuities of Darboux functions are essential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)#Darboux_function), but essential discontinuities contradict injectivity.
4. If one considers "connected" instead of "path-connected", the Conjecture is false, by considering the graph of the topologist sine curve $g$ with $g(0):=(0,0)$ ($g(t):= (t,\sin(\frac 1t))$ for $t\in (0,1]$).
5. Let us now assume $f$ is not (right-)continuous at $0$, and normalize $f(0)=0$. I think user TheEmptyFunction's answer to the above linked MO post https://mathoverflow.net/a/353018/112504 also applies here to tell us that there are arbitrarily small radii $\epsilon>0$ s.t. there is a sequence $y_n^\epsilon \searrow 0$ s.t. $f(y_n^\epsilon) \in C(0,\epsilon)$  ---- (illustrated below as the blue points, which I think we can normalize via pre-composing with a homeomorphism of $[0,1]$ and post-composing with a homeomorphism of $\mathbb R^2$ to be $\{\frac 1m: m \in \mathbb N^+\}$ in the domain, and $i\cdot e^{-\pi/2 \cdot \frac 1m})$ in the codomain, with $\epsilon=1$)

   [image: initial segments mapped to path connected]

   By mapping $(\frac 1{m+1},\frac 1m]$ to the line segment between $0\in \mathbb C$ (not inclusive) and $i\cdot e^{-\pi/2 \cdot \frac 1m} \in \mathbb C$ (inclusive) in a linear manner say (illustrated above), we get an injective map $[0,1]\to \mathbb R^2$ that maps any interval $[0,a\rangle$ (where the right-hand bracket $\rangle$ denotes both "$)$" and "$]$") to a path-connected set in $\mathbb R^2$ (perhaps we could say this function is a "initial-segment path-connected map"); but any interval $(0,a\rangle$ would not map to a path-connected set.

   This example is a "near miss" to the Conjecture.

$$$$

---

---

**One idea:** projection onto 1st and 2nd coordinates are both continuous maps, hence preserve path-connectedness. Thus if $f:=[t\mapsto (x(t),y(t))]:[0,1] \to \mathbb R^2$ is a path-connected map, $x,y:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ must be as well. As I mentioned above, a well-known class of non-continuous path-connected maps $[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ are the "everywhere locally surjective" functions. By postcomposing with a homeomorphism $\mathbb R \to (0,1)$, we can think of $x,y$ as "everywhere locally surjective" maps $x,y:[0,1]\to (0,1)$.

Then to make $f$ bijective, we need $y$ to be injective when restricted on each fiber $x^{-1}(r)$ for all $r\in \mathbb R$ (where each such fiber is dense in the domain), and vice versa ($x$ injective when restricted to each fiber $y^{-1}(r)$ for all $r\in \mathbb R$). Maybe something like this could work ***if*** we can partition $[0,1]$ into disjoint classes $C_\alpha$ where each $C_\alpha \cap x^{-1}(r)$ contains exactly 1 element (so each $C_\alpha$ contains exactly one element that gets mapped to $r$, for each real number $r$), and ***if*** $y$ attains a different constant value $c_\alpha$ on each $C_\alpha$. And to make $y$ "everywhere locally surjective" we need each $C_\alpha$ to be dense in $[0,1]$.

However I doubt that such a function preserves path-connectedness; it sends any interval $(a,b)$ (or $[a,b)$, etc.) to a set with lots of pieces of horizontal and vertical lines; if the pieces are too fragmented, we won't get path connectivity. I can imagine that if $y$ was monotone on $x^{-1}(r)$ or something, then we would see a longer vertical line piece at $x=r$; but unfortunately as [I commented here](https://%20https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3326686/prove-or-disprove-that-there-does-not-exist-a-monotone-function-f-mathbbr-ri#comment10085941_3326699) this desired monotonicity is not possible.

$$\newcommand{\im}{\operatorname{im}} \newcommand{\harmonicint}[1]{[\frac 1{#1+1},\frac 1{#1}]} \newcommand{\harmonicintt}[1]{[1/({#1+1}),1/{#1}]}$$

---

---

## Infinitely Many Discontinuities, and Trees

> In working with the previous near-miss example, I got the impression that in fact **MiniConjecture:** one point $p$ of discontinuity of $f$ begets infinitely many points of discontinuity converging to $p$, making such a potential discontinuous $f$ quite difficult to imagine. Unfortunately I could not prove this **MiniConjecture**.

#### Attempted proof that 1 discontinuity begets infinitely many:

Since we know that each $[0, \frac 1m]$ maps to a path-connected set containing $f(\frac 1m)$ and $f(0)=0$, let us **define**:

- paths $P_m : [-\frac 1m, 0] \to f([0, \frac 1m])\subseteq \mathbb R^2$, which we can assume to be injective by e.g. [Equivalence of Path-Connectedness and Arc-Connectedness for Hausdorff Spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2555101/equivalence-of-path-connectedness-and-arc-connectedness-for-hausdorff-spaces), or [using Zorn's lemma (article by Jeremy Brazas)](https://www.wcupa.edu/sciences-mathematics/mathematics/jBrazas/documents/Constructing_arcs_from_paths_9-9-21.pdf) --- illustrated below in orange.
- and paths $F_m: [-\frac 1m, - \frac 1{m+1}] \to f([\frac 1{m+1},\frac 1m]) \subseteq \mathbb R^2$ going from $f(\frac 1m)$ to $f(\frac 1{m+1})$ (which we can again assume injective; and furthermore because $f$ is injective, the paths $F_m$ will be disjoint except touching perhaps at endpoints $f(\frac 1m)$) --- illustrated below in green.

Now if $f|_{[1/(m+1),1/m]}$ is continuous as a function $[\frac 1{m+1},\frac 1m]\hookrightarrow \mathbb R^2$, [then](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Bijection_from_Compact_to_Hausdorff_is_Homeomorphism) $f|_{[1/(m+1),1/m]}$ is in fact a homeomorphism onto its image $f(\harmonicint m) \supseteq \im(F_m)$. So its inverse is a continuous map, mapping the path-connected set $\im(F_m)$ to path-connected set in $\harmonicint m$ containing $\frac 1{m+1},\frac 1m$ (since the path $F_m$ goes through those points), meaning $f^{-1}$ maps $\im(F_m) \subseteq f(\harmonicint m)$ to all of $\harmonicint m$, implying that $f|_{\harmonicintt m}$ is in fact a continuous bijection ([and hence](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Bijection_from_Compact_to_Hausdorff_is_Homeomorphism) homeomorphism) $\harmonicint m \to \im(F_m) = f(\harmonicint m)$.

So if $f$ is continuous on $(0,\eta)$ for some $\eta>\frac 1M >0$, then
all $\harmonicint m$ inside $(0,\eta)$ will be mapped by $f$ to a path from $f(\frac 1{m+1})$ to $f(\frac 1m)$; in other words, $f$ is composed of all these paths $F_m$ stitched together at the endpoints.

Now if I had the injective continuous path $P_M :[-\frac 1M, 0] \hookrightarrow f([0,\frac 1M])$ that goes through $f(\frac 1M)$ and $f(0)=0$, the fact that $f((0,\frac 1M])$ is the continuous image of $(0,1]$ (so a path/"ray" with a perhaps infinite "tail" that may wiggle a lot, but still pass through all of the points $f(\frac 1m)$ illustrated below), intuitively $P_M$ must end up travelling along this "ray".

Then one would hope to get a contradiction because if $P_M$ travels along this ray, then it would be forced to continue to come across the points $f(\frac 1m)$ (blue points in below pictures), and because the points $f(\frac 1m)$ are so far from $f(0)=0$, this would contradict that $P_M$ is a continuous path $[-\frac 1M, 0] \hookrightarrow f([0,\frac 1M])$.

Sadly after making many attempts in which I kept finding mistakes, I gave up trying to prove this **MiniConjecture**, though I suspect that it can be proven by making the above intuition/hand-waving rigorous.
$$$$

---

In any case, assuming $f:[0,1] \hookrightarrow \mathbb R^2$ has a discontinuity at $p\in [0,1]$ (e.g. $p=0$ as I normalized above), the paths $F_m$ and $P_m$ that are guaranteed (by path-connectedness of the map $f$) make us have a picture that looks like what follows, with the green $F_m$ paths and orange $P_m$ paths. If indeed we have infinitely many points of discontinuity (illustrated in red) converging to $p$ from the right, then each of those points will lead to another version of this tree structure in the codomain (which I have suggested in the small circles around the red points in the codomain).

[image: diagram for proof of infinite discontinuities]

All images of intervals $[p, p+\eta\rangle$ (where "$\rangle$" refers to both "$)$" and "$]$") will map to such a tree. Subtracting 2 such intervals leads to general intervals $\langle p+\delta, p+\eta\rangle$ which get mapped to a tree like above, with some portion (portions on the left in the above picture) cut off. But if the tree is super "well-connected" with threads weaving throughout the "canopy", I can imagine that the set remains path-connected.

So perhaps the **Conjecture** above is false, if one can construct an injective map from $[0,1]$ to this fractal tree-like structure.

$%[![simplified path connected tree thingy][8]][8]$

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4755663/must-injective-path-connected-maps-path-darboux-functions-be-continuous.  In particular, by my answer there, assuming CH the answer is no if you consider maps to $\mathbb{R}^3$ instead.

Comment: @EricWofsey sorry it seems like your link is to the wrong post. I indeed had the suspicion that the answer might depend on set theoretic issues — good thing I tagged ‘set theory’

Comment: Oops, I meant to link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1571091/is-a-path-connected-bijection-f-colon-bbbrn-to-bbbrn-continuous.